# El Pussycat bass line predecessors

Tags: jazz, soul, reggae

There's a bass figure that was prominent in 1960s Jamaican music:  56161, all eighth notes.  It was borrowed by the Staple Singers for "I'll Take You There".  It's heard in "The Liquidator", "Skinhead Moonstomp", Derrick Morgan's "Moon Hop", "Girl I've Got a Date", "El Pussycat Ska", and Mongo Santamaria's original Latin groover "El Pussycat".

That's where I lose the trail.  561 figures were frequent in Motown, but I don't know of any predecessors that approximate that specific 56161 pattern.

Anyone?